# PHP cloning object results in more than one objects?

Tags: php, count, clone

First I show the code:

```
//item duplication code goes here
elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'duplicate'){
    $array_index = $_REQUEST['array_index'];
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    $tempItem = clone $cart[$array_index];
    $cart[]=$tempItem;
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
}
```

For example, if I have 1 item in the shopping cart, pressing the link will give me 2 identical ones. The fact is, the immediate result is correct(I open the link in new tab) But after I refresh the page(old tab), it gives me 3 .

To explain, please see a short video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OORcT5KxZqw

I really don't understand why it's happening. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: is it because when you refresh the page you submit the form data again?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder but I didn't. I opened a new tab and refreshed the original. Try that Youtube link!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with your code is that if a `$_REQUEST` of `action` equals value `duplicate` then you are doing the following things:

1. get the cart from the session (which is previously stored)
2. clone the cart and store it in temp
3. and then copy back the temp into the cart
4. and finally store the cart into the session
5. Then i suppose you display your card somewhere...

What is happening here is that the cloning instructions should be valid only when you click the duplicate link.  I suppose you have your PHP in the same file as the html so when you open it in a new window the cart is updated with 2 items and stored in session (which is common to all instances of your page) and when you reload your page the same 2 items are fetched from the session and showed to you.  Also here you need to observe that the `$_REQUEST['action']` is still present so its duplicating 1 item more.  Now whenever you refresh the page it will keep on duplicating 1 item more.

As a solution to this try unsetting the action by using the `unset()` function after you have cloned the cart so that the php runs only when needed.

Comment: The duplicate URL is like `domain.com/showCart.php?array_index=0&action=duplicate`. Using Get or Request doesn't make a difference. However, when i refresh `showCart.php`(remember I opened in a new tab), this is when the extra one comes from. (Yes you're right, I was going to the same page)

Comment: @Xaio so where are you stuck?  I cannot understand what you are trying to achieve fully. Do you need that when you refresh the original page you should see 2 duplications and not 3?

Comment: Exactly! 2, not 3! `$cart[]=$tempItem;` this line is behavioring strangely

Comment: @Xaio did you try using `array_push($arrayname,$value)` instead then? Also what you are trying to do can be done without cloning too... And are the members of `$_SESSION['cart']` objects of a class or simple variables?

Comment: `array_push` gave me identical result. I want to clone it because it was an object keeping reference to numbers and strings. If I don't clone, changing the copy's variables will also change the old one's variables. Each member of `$_SESSION['cart']` is a custom-defined object.

Comment: @Xiao well I tried your code in my system and it works pretty well I get the right amount of duplicated items when i refresh the main page.  Check if your main page doesn't have any duplication info in the URL.  I ran the code and its working perfectly. If you want I can show it to you.  Also it would be better if u can show the video with your address bar.

Comment: @Xiao let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1941/discussion-between-lonewolfs-and-xiao)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is giving you three when you refresh the page because the old `$_REQUEST['array_index']` is still hanging around.  You need to set a session variable to indicate that the action has been completed, and check it before proceeding to do this action.

```
elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == 'duplicate'){

    // Check if you already duplicated this array_index
    if (!isset($_SESSION['duplication_done']) || (isset($_SESSION['duplication_done']) &&  $_SESSION['duplication_done'] != $_REQUEST['array_index']) {
      $array_index = $_REQUEST['array_index'];
      $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
      $tempItem = clone $cart[$array_index];
      $cart[]=$tempItem;
      $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;

      // After duplicating, store this array_index in $_SESSION
      $_SESSION['duplication_done'] = $_REQUEST['array_index'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent further duplication even if someone wanted to!? (e.g. purposely clicking duplicate again)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what's wrong with `array_index`. I thought it was about `action`? Neither do I get the `done` thing. Do you mean the code will be called twice?

Answer (score 0):

As [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.request.php) also holds [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.get.php), I'd guess your `&action=duplicate` sits in the url and your code get's executed as often as you reload the page.

I would suggest to redirect (using `header('Location: ...');`, see: [header](http://php.net/manual/function.header.php)) after the duplication, but only after removing the `action`-var from the url.

**Update**:

Using the function [getUrlCurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829087/php-unset-get-paramter/6829244#6829244) here's a short example:

```
function getUrlCurrently($filter = array()) {
    $pageURL = isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on" ? "https://" : "http://";

    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];

    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
    }

    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];


    if (strlen($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) > 0) {
        $pageURL = rtrim(substr($pageURL, 0, -strlen($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])), '?');
    }

    $query = $_GET;
    foreach ($filter as $key) {
        unset($query[$key]);
    }

    if (sizeof($query) > 0) {
        $pageURL .= '?' . http_build_query($query);
    }

    return $pageURL;
}

if ($_REQUEST['action'] == 'duplicate'){
    // your duplication code here ...

    // after the duplication
    header('Location: ' . getUrlCurrently(array(
        'action', 'array_index' // <--- unsetting the problematic url-vars
    )));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I tried to change `Request` to `Get`, but it didn't help. I actually didn't redirect to anywhere, but was a link linking to the same page. Any idea about that?

Comment: @Xiao the thing about request/get was just a hint. And I didn't mean that you are linking anywhere, but that you should. I'll try to give an code example of what I mean.